# How to change a string based on its content in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to change the names column in a dataset to just the person's last name so that I can consolidate by family; i.e. John Smith, Mary Smith, Josette Smith will all be named just Smith. I have tried to use Regex but cannot find a way to tell the program to consider all value before the 'Smith'. I will run it on a column so I tried to standardize it by not hard coding the names in.

I have tried:

```
child1['full_name'].replace({' * Smith':'Smith'},
                                      regex=True, inplace = True)
```

where I would like to know if I can place something in the place of the asterisk to do what I want it to do. Currently, it just concatenates the word before Smith and yields 'JohnSmith, 'MarySmith'...

A little guidance will help a great lot.

Comment: Use `.*` to match anything before `Smith`.

Comment: Your regexp only matches spaces before `Smith`.

Comment: `child['full_name'].str.split(' ').str[-1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'full_name':["Mary Smith", "Rose Smith", "Lisa Blaid"]})
df['full_name'].replace({r'\S+\s+Smith':'Smith'},regex=True, inplace = True)
```

Out:

```py
>>> dr
    full_name
0       Smith
1       Smith
2  Lisa Blaid
>>>
```

**Expression explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Smith                    'Smith'
```

Comment: Hi Ryszard, this is partially working; but it's not working on names that are longer than 2. For example, Edward Larky Smith returns as Edward Smith.

Comment: @Yoko Then use `r'.*\s+Smith'`

Comment: @Yoko Please also kindly upvote the answer.